# html links in the project directory Xcode project are not opening

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have the compete website of my project..
I have to make it local
while using uiwebview
it only detect the page that is set to open
i.e mainpage
it shows the links but it is not opening them

I have included the all html files in the project

I need reputation to show you the page image.. so tell me how can i improve my answer 
or

Comment: its really urgent please help me out...

Comment: You need import also javascript file or only HTML file?

Comment: it will work enough for me if only html works

Comment: "- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//    self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
           [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainpage" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"test"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];"

Comment: please  pleaseeeee...
help me out of this

Comment: when i tap the link it seems it is pressed
but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For insert the HTML file into uiwebview you can use this method:

1. Drag your .html file into your Xcode project (select "Copy items into destination group's folder")
2. Open storyboard file
3. Drag Web View from Object Library to your View Controller
4. Show Assistant editor and drag with ctr+click the Web View just create under @interface section and before @end. Insert webView into name field and click on connect for create the following property:

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
5. into viewDidLoad method insert the following code for load your .html file

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name_HTML_file" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]];

   [self.webView loadRequest:request];
6. Build and run the app.